# How to solve this path integral over region?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

Any idea how to solve this functional integral?:

$$\Delta_\Sigma(x,y) \propto \int \exp\left(i \int\limits_\Sigma \phi(x)(\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu -m^2)\phi(x)  dx^4 \right) \phi(x)\phi(y)D[\phi]$$

With $\Sigma$ being a space-time region. When $\Sigma$ is the whole of space-time the LHS becomes the Feynman propagator (to within a constant factor).

I want to solve it where $\Sigma$ is a finite region. For example, if it were a spherical region. One could paramaterise the boundary of the region with $X^\mu(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$ for example. So th solution would be in terms of $X$, $x$ and $y$.

Any clues how to solve this for the general case? (If such a thing is even feasible?)

(The reason you might want to do this if the region $\Sigma$ was sandwiched between two arbitary Cauchy surfaces. Also just for mathematical curiosity).

Comment: *Σ being a space-time region ... if it were a spherical region ...* What is a spherical region of spacetime?

Comment: @Smith I would define it has $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=1$ for example. You may call it something different.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth pointing out that even in the 1d case, Gaussian integrals over finite (or even semi-finite) do not have closed form representations in terms of elementary functions. This is the entire purpose of defining the error function.

So while it *may* be possible to get something resembling a reasonable result from this integration in special cases, it seems like all hope is lost for arbitrary reasons...we can't even do this in the much simpler case of a well-defined 1-dimensional integral.

Comment: Well, I don't expect to get it in terms of elementary functions, but perhaps a series solution for example. Or a non-functional integral or indeed in terms of error functions if we consider error functions as elementary.

Comment: @zooby I doubt you would find a great deal of success in this endeavor. Generally, if something is not feasible with a regular integral, trying to do it with a functional integral won't make matters any better. A slightly different question you may wish to pose, as I think it would get you better answers: is it possible to define a propagator as the inverse of a kinetic term integrated over something other than Minkowski space.

Comment: @zooby I should also point out that you would only likely get responses about general spacetimes, not integrals over subspaces. If the integral is only over a subspace, then the path integral calculation is unrelated to time evolution and correlators on the Hilbert space. Hence I would be surprised if many people have put much thought into developing machinery to handle the problem you're posing.

Comment: I think you are right. But I find it surprising, since one can simply choose two cauchy surfaces and you have a subspace sandwiched between them. So it is quite a simple situation in QFT. But perhaps it is just not useful enough.

Comment: I think there may be a way by transforming it into momentum space. But it is not easy :)

Comment: @zooby Sure, but Fourier methods typically demand flat (Minkowski/Euclidean) and unbounded regions to work nicely. If there was a simple way to do this, gravity people would likely be all over it. See, for example, [Hartman's quantum gravity lectures](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/). But it's a worthwhile thing to ponder nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks! I saw these lectures a long time a ago but lost the link.